# How to create library for v lang by c++

Tags: c++, binding, vlang

I would like to ask how to create a module on c++ for v lang.
For example

с++

```cpp
int some_method() {
 return 6
}
```

v

```
import my_c_module
my_c_module.some_method()
```

I will be grateful for any information

And can I call c++ class method in v lang?

Answer (score 1):

In V every file in the root of a folder is part of the same module. Simple programs don't need to specify module name, in which case it defaults to 'main'.

V is a very modular language. Creating reusable modules is encouraged and is quite easy to do. To create a new module, create a directory with your module's name containing .v files with code:

```
cd ~/code/modules
mkdir mymodule
vim mymodule/myfile.v
```

Inside myfile.v

```
// myfile.v
module mymodule

// To export a function we have to use `pub`
pub fn say_hi() {
    println('hello from mymodule!')
}
```

Now you can call your module

```
import mymodule

fn main() {
    mymodule.say_hi()
}
```

You can create also your custom module, and [here](https://github.com/vlang/v/blob/master/doc/docs.md#publish-package) is the official docs